# Test Unit with php

Tags: php, phpunit, symfony4

I'm new in testunit with php, I need to test my function changeStatus with phpunit, but I have a problem to change value.

**Function ChangeStatus**

```
public function changeStatus(Genus $genus)
    {
        $isEnabled = $genus->getEnabled();
        $genusGroupTab = self::$entityManager->getRepository(Germ::class)
            ->findBy(['genus' => $genus->getId()]);

        if ($genusGroupTab != null) {
            /** @var Germ $germ */
            foreach ($genusGroupTab as $germ) {
                $germ->setEnabled(!$isEnabled);
                self::$entityManager->persist($germ);
                self::$entityManager->flush();
            }
        }
        $genus->setEnabled(!$isEnabled);
        $this->save($genus);

        return $genus->getEnabled();
    }
```

In my Class to test this I have this code :

```
public function testActiveGenusInactiveChangeStatus()
    {

        $genus = $this->createMock(Genus::class);
        $genus->method('setGenusLabel')->willReturn('fefeef');
        $genus->method('getId')->willReturn('3f3c6c06-5971-4e75-97ee-94543edafced');
        $genus->method('getGenusLabel')->willReturn('ACIDAMINOCOCCUS');
        $genus->method('getEnabled')->willReturn(false);


        $germe = new Germ();
        $germe->setGenus($genus);

        $repository = $this->getMockBuilder('Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectRepository')->getMock();

        $this->objectManager
            ->expects($this->once())
            ->method('getRepository')
            ->with(Germ::class)
            ->id($germe->getGenus()->getId())
            ->willReturn($repository);
        $paramGenus = $germe->getGenus();

        $this->assertFalse($this->managerGenus->changeStatus($paramGenus));

    }
```

I need to do this:

If the value of Genus is True but the function changeStatus need to return False, and if is False he need to return true.

But the Value Genus is False and is Return False.

Someone can help me please.

Comment: the return value of changeStatus is `return $genus->getEnabled();` which will be always false thanks to the mocking definition `$genus->method('getEnabled')->willReturn(false);`. The fact that you call setEnable(true) does not override the mocking value

Comment: I understand, thanks
But can you have a idea to change this value to true please?

Comment: I see two solutions: first one is to not use mocking for that method and do call the actual method instead. With then a setEnabled(false) before calling the changeStatus method. The second solution would be to use a verify (I played only with Mocking in java but I guess they have the equivalent here too) on the mocker to check that a setEnabled(true) has been called on $genus

Comment: I resolve it, i use a ReflectionObject to give object Id and it's work :)
Thanks

Comment: then please put your solution in an answer and close the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solve this with this code

> ```
>     $repository = $this->getMockBuilder('Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectRepository')->getMock(); $repository->expects($this->any())
>     ->method('findBy')
>     ->willReturn([$germe]);
> ```

In Manager Function i use foreach with a array but i returned a object repository not a array of Germ.
I just add [] to correct this